# What is the effect of changing relay port in vidalia control panel?

Tags: tor-browser-bundle

I have vidalia control panel and I am using xampp in development. I cannot start xampp and vidalia. I think both are using port 443.

How do I configure them to  work with them together  without conflicts

Comment: This really needs more information. There *may* be a port conflict if you've configured Tor to use that port for something. We'd need to see the details of your torrc or vidalia configuration to know if this is the case.

Answer (score 1):

Correct your XAMPP to bind to 127.0.0.1:443 explicitly and configure tor to bind **explicitly to the IP facing a way to Internet**. That's how it works, and it works fine, checked

Answer (score 0):

Tick the check box shown as in the diagram [the check box 'My firewall only lets me to connect to certain ports'](https://i.stack.imgur.com/g9N3x.png)[1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/g9N3x.png)